# Audio not saving on long length videos Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, camera, avfoundation

Hey i am using creating simple video recording applicaton where i am recording and saving the video in the album with different name.
But issue i am facing is that when we saving small videos like 20 sec its working fine.
But if we try to save 60 sec video the video is recorded but not audio 
Please have a look on my code, And correct me where i am getting wrong

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

videoCount = 0 ;


 [self switchCameraTapped:nil];

// Alloc Player



//---------------------------------
//----- SETUP CAPTURE SESSION -----
//---------------------------------
NSLog(@"Setting up capture session");
CaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

//----- ADD INPUTS -----
NSLog(@"Adding video input");

//ADD VIDEO INPUT
AVCaptureDevice *VideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (VideoDevice)
{
    NSError *error;
    VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        if ([CaptureSession canAddInput:VideoInputDevice])
            [CaptureSession addInput:VideoInputDevice];
        else
            NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
}



//ADD AUDIO INPUT
NSLog(@"Adding audio input");
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
if (audioInput)
{
    [CaptureSession addInput:audioInput];
}


//----- ADD OUTPUTS -----

//ADD VIDEO PREVIEW LAYER
NSLog(@"Adding video preview layer");
[self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:CaptureSession] ];

// PreviewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;      //<<SET ORIENTATION.  You can deliberatly set this wrong to flip the image and may actually need to set it wrong to get the right image

[[self PreviewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];


//ADD MOVIE FILE OUTPUT
NSLog(@"Adding movie file output");
MovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

Float64 TotalSeconds = 60;          //Total seconds
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;    //Frames per second
CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale);   //<<SET MAX DURATION
MovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;

MovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;                        //<<SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME

if ([CaptureSession canAddOutput:MovieFileOutput])
    [CaptureSession addOutput:MovieFileOutput];

//SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
// [self CameraSetOutputProperties];            //(We call a method as it also has to be done after changing camera)



//----- SET THE IMAGE QUALITY / RESOLUTION -----
//Options:
//  AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh - Highest recording quality (varies per device)
//  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium - Suitable for WiFi sharing (actual values may change)
//  AVCaptureSessionPresetLow - Suitable for 3G sharing (actual values may change)
//  AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 - 640x480 VGA (check its supported before setting it)
//  AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 - 1280x720 720p HD (check its supported before setting it)
//  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto - Full photo resolution (not supported for video output)
NSLog(@"Setting image quality");
[CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
if ([CaptureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])     //Check size based configs are supported before setting them
    [CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];



//----- DISPLAY THE PREVIEW LAYER -----
//Display it full screen under out view controller existing controls
NSLog(@"Display the preview layer");
CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[PreviewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
[PreviewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
//[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self CaptureManager] previewLayer]];
//We use this instead so it goes on a layer behind our UI controls (avoids us having to manually bring each control to the front):

UIView *CameraView = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
[[self view] addSubview:CameraView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:CameraView];

[[CameraView layer] addSublayer:PreviewLayer];

//----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
[CaptureSession startRunning];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self performSelector:@selector(StartFunctionality) withObject:nil afterDelay:valSequenceDelay];
// [self orientationChanged];

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

for ( AVCaptureConnection *connection in [MovieFileOutput connections] )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", connection);
    for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts] )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", port);
        if ( [[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
        }
    }
}

if([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) // **Here it is, its always false**
{
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:[self deviceOrientationDidChange]];
}

NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
NSString *albumName=strSessionName;
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName
                         resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                             NSLog(@"added album:%@", albumName);

                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"error adding album");
                        }];


}



#pragma mark- DID FINISH RECORDING TO OUTPUT FILE AT URL
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
  fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
            error:(NSError *)error
```

{

```
NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");

BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
if ([error code] != noErr)
{
    // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
    id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
    if (value)
    {
        RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
    }
}
if (RecordedSuccessfully)
{


    //----- RECORDED SUCESSFULLY -----
    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
    NSString *albumName=strSessionName;
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName
                             resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                                 NSLog(@"added album:%@", albumName);

                             }
                            failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                NSLog(@"error adding album");
                            }];



    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {

        //            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
        //                                        completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
        //             {
        //                 if (error)
        //                 {
        //
        //                 }
        //                 else{
        //
        //                 }
        //             }];
        //
        __block ALAssetsGroup* groupToAddTo;
        [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                               usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                   if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:albumName]) {
                                       NSLog(@"found album %@", albumName);
                                       groupToAddTo = group;
                                   }
                               }
                             failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                 NSLog(@"failed to enumerate albums:\nError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                             }];


        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            if (error) {

                NSLog(@"Final Video could not be saved");
            }
            else{

                [library assetForURL:assetURL
                         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                             // assign the photo to the album

                             [groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                             NSLog(@"Added %@ to %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename], albumName);
                             //                                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video Saved to HubRamped Album."  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
                             //                                 [alert show];
                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                            NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }];
            }
        }];

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Im not even going to read to code for errors, but one thing for sure: not all audio codecs work. One codec may work for one device the same will not. Same goes for iOS version. I have learned that from my audio recording app. Try using Apple Lossless if possible.

Comment: i have figured out what is happing in my code.... i have just added the following code and now its working fine.... [MovieFileOutput setMovieFragmentInterval:maxDuration];.... Thanks for reply